# Objects on the heap and references

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

While answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11272292/returning-by-reference-of-a-value-stored-as-a-pointer-memory-leak) I got a bit confused. We all know that this works fine due to the C++ copy semantics:

```
int *some_obj = new int(42);
int a_copy = *some_obj;

delete some_obj;

printf("The answer is %d\n", a_copy);
```

But what about this?

```
int *some_obj = new int(42);
int& a_ref = *some_obj;

delete some_obj;

printf("The answer is %d\n", a_ref);
```

Is this accessing deleted memory?

<sub>Probably asked various times in various forms, but this is not very Google friendly. Hell, I couldn't make a decent title.</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is. So that's not permitted. (You can ensure you see the difference by using a class with a destructor that changes the value.)

Comment: Now that I read a part of the Wikipedia page on it, it explains it very clearly in the last paragraph of [this section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(C%2B%2B)#Relationship_to_pointers). What about returning references to temporaries (A is some random class) `A& func() { return A(); }`?

Comment: That has the same problem. You are returning a reference to an object that no longer exists when the caller gets it.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly. Second example accesses released memory. Implementation of references is pointers. Very simple. Reference is a pointer that cannot be changed and it has different notation of the access operator. There is no other difference between them.